# How to find a parent link of a broken link with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, broken-links

I found a list of broken links on a web site.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String homePage = "http://www.example.com";
    String url = "";
    HttpURLConnection huc = null;
    int respCode = 200;

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(homePage);

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){

        url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

        System.out.println(url);

        if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
            continue;
        }

        if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){
            System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
            continue;
        }
            huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            huc.connect();

            respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

            if(respCode >= 400){
                System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
            }

    ...
```

But need to find the parent link. Where this broken URL is located (page URL). Is it possible to do it with selenium + (java + intellij idea)?
Algorithm (no need the code), thanks.

Comment: I don't get the question nor the scenario. Can you add some examples to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Sorry, added the code. As you see I get the url (var. url) and its respCode, if it's 404 or any other error I get this url. But I need to find this url on the website also (to fix), for this I need a URL where the broken URL is located(where it was called from). If it's possible.

Comment: If the duplicate is incorrect, post an example of the "parent" you expect.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you a lot.